# How to get data from a page back to the main window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my `MainWindow.cs` class, I have tab control where I instantiate different pages.  I can send data to the page by overloading the constructor. However, when the pages make changes to the 'foo' object I am sending in, how do I pick up those changes back in `Mainwindow`?

MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        foo.FooName = "foo Name";
        foo.FooNumber = 99;
    }

    //Event that controls tabbing and loads page resources.
    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.tabProfile != null && this.tabProfile.IsSelected)
        {
            this.Main.Content = new TestPage(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Test Page:

```
public TestPage(Foo foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.FooName + "  " + foo.FooNumber.ToString());

    //How do I get these changes back to MainWindow.cs?
    foo.FooName = "Foo Name Change";
    foo.FooNumber = 222;   

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do it, but the good news to you is that you don't need to do anything. Objects are sent by reference when you use them in function parameters, unlike primitive types which are sent by value (i.e. as a copy).

That means, when you change the properties of your `foo` object in the other form or function, you are actually changing the properties of the same original `foo` object. So if you check the `foo` object back in your `MainWindow` after the other form changes it, you will see the new values.